# Resetting Redmine project repository

Tags: git, svn, redmine, svn-repository

I've got a problem with a project repository setting in Redmine, in that; I've tried to set a repository with GIT, entered an invalid GIT path, and now I'm stuck as I can't seem to delete the path which has been set.
[image]

Clicking delete sends me to the next page, stating that the following;
[image]

Ideally I want to delete this repository reference, and put in a SVN repository instead. I've tried to rejig the system by taking out GIT in the Administration/Settings/Repositories panel, and leaving just Subversion. However, this does nothing for the project's stuck GIT repository setting.

What file should I edit to delete these project settings? I'm a bit wary, as I don't want my project potentially corrupted.

UPDATE 26/10/2010 : I've raised [Defect #6713](http://www.redmine.org/issues/6713#change-21595) with the Redmine project

Also I was missing GIT a system variable from the environmental variables, now added the following, enabling me to know delete the respository
;C:\msysgit\msysgit\cmd;C:\msysgit\msysgit\bin;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bug in Redmine. I just looked through my Redmine installation and can't find the place where the URL is stored, it's probably in the database. If I were in your situation and didn't have time to waste, I would:
1) make a backup, just in case,
2) create an empty Git repository somewhere (or even take any public repo, since you can put an URL in there),
3) configure Redmine to point to that repository to get unstuck,
4) now, configure Redmine to use your real Subversion repo,
5) report bug.

Comment: I've tried this, however an error is still thrown with this URL git://repo.or.cz/KFingerManager.git  a public one I prised on the net http://repo.or.cz/w/KFingerManager.git

Comment: I've also tried setting the "Path to .git directory" to C:\testgit\  however this causes an error as well

Answer (score 0):

There is a delete button (right bottom) on that page (repository) which you can press and after that you can create the entry for the repository from scratch.

Comment: I've tried clicking delete, and get the error detailed in my original description

Comment: Just stop the Apache/WebBrick or Mongrels cluster completely and make a restart and try a second time to delete the repository from the project configuration If this does not work check the issued of Redmine itself..

Comment: I tried doing the steps you've asked, but the same error appears. :-(

Comment: That sounds like a real bug. ;-(